# Displaying unlimited amount of specific elements from a yml file object

Tags: html, liquid

So I have a page that displays stories with a brief summary, and when clicking on individual stories you can view a more in depth modal containing more detail about the story clicked on. My problem occurs when displaying the images within the "fullstory" (more detailed version). I want to be able to display infinite pictures inside the story based on how many images are included inside the yml file.

The YML file contains stories such as:

```
- name: The Playful Story
  description: Joy Project volunteers built a sensory gym for a family with children who have special needs.
  image_url: sensory-gym
  date_of_event: April 2015
  uniqueID: 0008
  fullheader: Sensory Gym Build Day
  fullstory: In January of 2015, over a dozen Joy Project volunteers built a sensory gym for a family with several children with special needs. We created a room for the children to enjoy that included a climbing structure, suspended equipment, and several sensory toys. <br>Check out the video below for a further look into our day!
  fullimage: sensory-gym
  embededvideo: #
```

and the YML objects are read by the following HTML:

```
{% for story in site.data.stories %}
     <h3 class="center" >{{story.name}}</h3>

     <!-- Short Description -->
     <p><b>Date of Event: </b> {{story.date_of_event}}</p>
     <p>{{story.description}}</p>

<h3 class="center" >{{story.name}}</h3>

                <!-- Short Description -->
            <p><b>Date of Event: </b> {{story.date_of_event}}</p>
            <p>{{story.description}}</p>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal{{story.uniqueID}}" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title center">{{story.fullheader}}</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>{{story.fullstory}}</p>

        <!-- Display up to 3 images -->
        {% for story.fullimage in story %} <!-- Image 1 spot -->
        <img class="center" id="{{story.fullimage}}" src="/assets/img/stories/{{story.fullimage}}.png" alt="{{story.name}}" style="padding-bottom: 10px">
        {% endif %}
        <!-- /Image area --> 

        {% if story.embededvideo %} <!-- Video spot -->
        <br><object data="{{story.embededvideo}}" width="560" height="315"></object>
        {% endif %}

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div> <!-- Close Modal --> 

        {% endfor %}
```

Long story short there's a multiple stories within a YML file called "stories.yml" and I would like to give each one indefinite amounts of "fullimage" and it display all of them inside the modal. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First set up your yml to hold all of the images

```
- name: The Playful Story
  description: Joy Project volunteers built a sensory gym for a family with children who have special needs.
  image_url: sensory-gym
  images:
     - url: sensory-gym-1
       alt: Use alt text on your images for better SEO
     - url: sensory-gym-2
       alt: Use alt text on your images for better SEO
     - url: sensory-gym-3
       alt: Use alt text on your images for better SEO
  date_of_event: April 2015
  uniqueID: 0008
  fullheader: Sensory Gym Build Day
```

Then you can loop over them:

```
{% for image in story.images %}
   <img class="center" id="{{ image.url }}" src="/assets/img/stories/{{ image.url }}.png" alt="{{ image.alt }}" style="padding-bottom: 10px">
{% endfor %}
```

If you wish to seperate the first three images from other ones you can use a counter:

```
{% assign count = 0 %}
{% for image in story.images %}
  {% assign count = count | plus: 1 %}
  {% if count < 3 %}
    <img class="center" id="{{ image.url }}" src="/assets/img/stories/{{ image.url }}.png" alt="{{ image.alt }}" style="padding-bottom: 10px">
  {% else %}
     {% break %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```